# Integer returning NumberFormatException when parsing using Integer.parseInt

Tags: java, integer

I am working on a project that requires me to parse a String into an Integer. I have not had this problem before, but when I try to parse a String to an Integer, I get this message

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "385.3100"`, where 385.3100 is the integer in question. Nothing I have done is working.

`String close = (closing.get("4. close").toString()); int money = Integer.parseInt(close);`  Is my code, where closing is a JSONObject.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have to use `Double.parseDouble()`.

Comment: Yeah, that worked. I don't know how I forgot to do that, but I appreciate the timely response! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**385.3100** is not an integer but a number with decimal precision. Use:

`Double.parseDouble()`
or
`Float.parseFloat()`